# How do I throw an exception to a specific thread in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to create a timeout, where if a function doesn't finish execution in time, a default value is returned. What I have below seems like it would work, except that the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised in the main thread, whereas my callback function is in a separate thread.

Is there any way in Python of specifying which thread the exception is raised in?

```py
def interrupt():
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

def callback_function():
    # Start 16 ms timer
    timer = threading.Timer(0.016, interrupt)
    timer.start()
    try:
        result = inconsistent_execution_time_function(data)
        timer.cancel()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Long execution time")
        result = default
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

As you surmised your solution doesn't work because `threading.Timer()` is implemented using a separate thread (not the main thread) and thus can't propagate an exception to the original thread. Your approach won't work.

The usual solution is to employ a cooperative approach. Create a context object, possibly using thread local storage. That context object starts out with the boolean representing whether a timeout occurred set to false. Your `interrupt()` function sets that var to true. Your `inconsistent_execution_time_function()` then periodically checks whether the var is true.

But if you absolutely want to send a signal, possibly to interrupt a long running syscall, you should use `signal.pthread_kill()` in your timer function. Obviously you will need to send the thread ID of your `callback_function()` to that function by adding an appropriate parameter to its definition and add a `args=(threading.ident)` parameter to the `threading.Timer()` call.

Comment: Thanks. The `inconsistent_execution_time_function()` is basically an API call, so can't monitor itself, unfortunately. Launching it in a new process required too much overhead, so I just created a longer buffer for it.